# Xcode does not compile category

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have added a category to my Xcode project using `File > New > Category`. I noticed that in Xcode the code completion does not work and even if I add garbage to the class the compiler does not complain.

This is my class:

```
#import "MyClass+Category.h"

@implementation MyClass (Category)

a
sdf
ads
f@asdlkfjhaslfäasdlföjölfasdf

@end
```

The `.m` file has the correct target membership and is in the `Compile Sources` build phase. What is going wrong. I also tried to restart Xcode to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's embarassing. I did not have the proper target set so it was my framework that was being compiled instead of the code I was writing.